# Applying changes to an element if words occur nth times

Tags: javascript, this, parent

Firstly I'm attempting to determine if an element contains a words an nth number of time which I have been able to do using this function

```
function wc(string, word) {
        var length = typeof string === "string" && typeof word === "string" && word.length,
            loop = length,
            index = 0,
            count = 0;
        while (loop) {
            index = string.indexOf(word, index);
            if (index !== -1) {
                count += 1;
                index += length;
            } else {
                loop = false;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

var innerH1 = h1.innerHTML,
        findWord = "<br>";  
    var h1Check = document.createElement("div");    
    h1Check.style.display = "none";
    h1Check.innerHTML = (wc(innerH1, findWord));
```

However rather than repeat the bottom part for individual elements I am now trying to apply this to all elements of the same class by adding a child span to that class which counts the occurrence of a particular word within it's parent element and will determine a change if it occurs an nth amount of times.

Is anyone able to see where I went wrong in the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/garyvoss/xp1bnace/)?

Note JQuery can't be used.

Answer (score 0):

line  `var innerH1 = headers.innerHTML`, you missed index should be `var innerH1 = headers[i].innerHTML,`
also many bugs in code,

should be in for loop.

```
    if(newSpan.innerHTML === "1") 
    { newSpan.parentElement.style.color = "red"; }
    else if(newSpan.innerHTML === "2") 
    { newSpan.parentElement.style.color = "blue"; }
```